# Do we need clojure-contrib.jar in clojure 1.4?

Tags: clojure

I have a simple question, do we need clojure-contrib.jar  along with clojure latest version 1.4 or does it include everything. If it does not include then where I can get latest version of clojure-contrib.jar.

Kindly help

Regards
Mohtashim

Comment: It looks like Michael answered your question, could you please select it as accepted?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Please don't use clojure.contrib. It is not maintained.

For Clojure 1.3 release, clojure-contrib was split: some parts are now part of the Clojure standard library, some are individual libraries under github.com/clojure, some (poor quality or unmaintained) libraries parts were not migrated. For more information, see [Where Did clojure.contrib Go](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go).

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. So in short whatever functionality was being provided by clojure.contrib, that is already available in clojure.jar for 1.4 or there is some other library to be included.

Comment: I got it. It has been included in clojure.jar file which is good.

Comment: Some of the features are in clojure.java.io and so on. Some are standalone libraries. It really depends on what specifically you need from the old contrib.

Comment: It hasn't been mentioned but those that were not migrated and dont have maintainers are no longer available. If you want to use them then one solution is to copy the source code of the function you're after at http://clojuredocs.org